# How to make reasoning of classes with property chain

Tags: owl, semantic-web, ontology, protege

I have an OWL2 ontology combining technological processes and numerical models. I need to find out, which process might be modeled with which model. I introduced Requirements, that areFulfilled by Process while Models hasRequirements. I am able to do it with individuals, but not classes.

I am using Protege 5.1, Fact++ reasoner.

Classes:

- Processes

  - Proc1 `EquivalentTo: Processes and (fulfillRestriction exactly 1 Req1)`
- Requirements

  - Req1 `Equivalent to Requirements and (hasTemperature exactly 1 (temperature only xsd:double[ "5.0"^^xsd:double , <= "150.0"^^xsd:double])`
- Models

  - Model1 `EquivalentTo: Models and (hasRestriction exactly 1 Req1)`

Now I have an object property:

`ObjectProperty: testIsModelOf
    SubPropertyChain: hasRestriction o  inverse (fulfillRestriction)`

I defined individuals:

```
Individual: mod1

    Types: Model1

    Facts: hasRestriction  requir1

Individual: requir1

    Types: Req1

Individual: process1

    Types: 
        Proc1

    Facts: fulfillRestriction  requir1
```

Asking for (with DLQuery):

`Models that testIsModelOf some Proc1`

If I define individuals for those three classes and define object properties between them, the result is as expected (DLQuery says mod1 is an instance of `Models that testIsModelOf some Proc1`). I expected that I will also get the Model1 class as a Direct Subclass (or equivalent class?) of the query result, but it does not happen. Is this possible to get the class, not only individual - without SWRL?

Comment: why do you think that `Model1` is a subclass of it? All you know about `Model1` is that it is equivalent and therefore also a subclass of `Models and (hasRestriction exactly 1 Req1)` - but what about `fulfillRestriction`? I mean `Proc1` isn't used anywhere in other axioms,  not sure if you forgot something. So, I don't see any "relation" from `Model1` to `fulfillRestriction`, but maybe I'm missing something here

Comment: The DLQuery shows that an individual belonging to the class Model1 (I am adding definitions of individuals to the query) belongs also to the class `Models that testIsModelOf some Proc1`. Since the definition of Model1 is in fact `hasRestriction exactly 1 Req1`, which is further used in property chain `testIsModelOf`, I expected that **each** individual belonging to `Model1` will also belong to `Models that testIsModelOf some Proc1`. If it is true for each individual, that's mean that whole `Model1` class is equivalent to `Models that testIsModelOf some Proc1`. Am I wrong?